# Use eloquent relation on models returning by another method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a `Category` model which has `belongsToMany` relation with `Product` model via a pivot table called `product_to_category`
I can get all products in a `Category` with $category->products() and then apply a Filter scope to it to filter the result with parameters given in `Request` like this:

When I send this request :

`http://site.dev/category/205?product&available&brand`

I apply the parameters like this:

`Category::find($id)->products()->filter($request)`

The problem is when I want to get all product in a category and its children. The existing `products` relation gives me products in only given category.

I tried to modify the `products()` method in `Category` model as this:

```
  public function products()
    {
        return DB::table('oc_product')
            ->join('oc_product_to_category', 'oc_product_to_category.category_id', '=', 'oc_product_to_category.category_id')
            ->join('oc_category_path', 'oc_category_path.category_id', '=', 'oc_category.category_id')
            ->whereIn('oc_product_to_category.category_id', $this->children(true));
    }
```

But when I this code :

`Category::find($id)->products()->filter($request)`

I get this exception error:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()
```

I know that filter scope is defined in Model class, but how can I apply that `filter` scope to QueryBuilder which is returned by modified `products` method?

Here are my classes :

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function scopeFilter( $request, QueryFilter $filters ) {
        return $filters->apply( $request );
    }


    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Category::class, 'product_to_category', 'product_id', 'category_id' );
    }
}
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }

    public function children($id_only = false)
    {
        $ids = $this->hasMany(CategoryPath::class, 'path_id', 'category_id')
            ->join('category', 'category.category_id', '=', 'category_path.category_id')
            ->where('category.status', 1)
            ->pluck('category.category_id');

        if ($id_only)
            return $ids;

        return self::find($ids);
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        $parent = DB::Select("SELECT  cp.path_id AS category_id FROM category_path cp LEFT JOIN category_description cd1 
                        ON (cp.path_id = cd1.category_id AND cp.category_id != cp.path_id) 
                        WHERE cd1.language_id = '2' AND cp.category_id = " . $this->category_id);

        return $parent;
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_to_category', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

QueryFilter class:

```
abstract class QueryFilter {

    protected $request;
    protected $builder;

    public function __construct( Request $request ) {

        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function filters() {
        return $this->request->all();
    }

    public function apply( Builder $builder ) {
        $this->builder = $builder;

        foreach ( $this->filters() as $name => $value) {
            if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
                call_user_func_array([$this, $name], array_filter([$value]));
            }
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }
}
```

CategoryFilter class:

```
class CategoryFilters extends QueryFilter
{
    public function id($id)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('category_id', $id);
    }

    public function procons()
    {
        return $this->builder->with('pros', 'cons');
    }

    public function available()
    {
        return $this->builder->where('quantity', '>', 0);
    }

    public function optionValues()
    {
        return $this->builder->with('optionValues');
    }

    public function description()
    {
        return $this->builder->with('description');
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->builder->with('images');
    }

    public function order($order)
    {
        $params = explode(',', $order);
        $order = isset($params[0]) ? $params[0] : null;
        $way = isset($params[1]) && strtolower($params[1]) == 'desc' ? $params[1] : 'asc';

        if ($order) {
            return $this->builder->orderBy($order, $way);
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code of how you get all product in a category and its children?

Comment: @wanghanlin I can only get all products in a category with `$category->products()`, but I can't get products in its children categories. that's my problem!

Comment: @wanghanlin Parent/Children relation of categories is defined in another table called category_path

Comment: I see, i think it's quite impossible to fetch child category products as you are querying a relationship that laravel automatically added where category_id = id. Why not just fetch from Product model, using Product::whereIn('category_id', Category::find(id)->children(true)) then apply filter?

Comment: @wanghanlin  I'll try that and let you know

Comment: @wanghanlin Great idea! ;) I had to use this code `Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                    $query->whereIn('product_to_category.category_id', $category->children(true));
                })`

Comment: @wanghanlin you can write it down as an answer an I'll accept it

Comment: right, I miss that it's belongsToMany not hasMany. it's ok, I didn't solve the problem, I think it may better have some kind of relationship that extend `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation` like belongsToManyThrough to solve this problem.